# VueJS3 extra "/" in route

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

My code is working fine but I notice an ugly extra "/" i the link url (which appear like "http://localhost:5173/%2FLink" in the browser address bar). I dont like it and I would like to have a clean url. How can I remove it?
I have the following template :

```
<template>
    <div class="mystyle">
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'page1', params: { sub: post_data.link }}"><div class="linkstyle">{{ post_data.link }}</div></router-link>
        </router-link>
    </div>
  </template>
```

And the route in route/index.js

```
routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: HomeView
    },
    {
      path: '/:sub',
      name: 'page1',
      component: PageView
    },
  ]
```

I tried to remove the "/" in the path property of the route but vuejs doesnt like it. I put it back.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? An extra '/' at the end? Or the converted url in the browser adress bar?

Comment: In the browser address bar the url is "http://localhost:5173/%2FLink" instead of "http://localhost:5173/Link"

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce. This is not something that's expected for the code you posted and could be considered a bug.

Comment: Finally yes there was an extra / in the post_data.link. Not an issue

Answer (score 0):

remove / in the path property of route config.

```
<router-link :to="`/${post_data.link.trim()}`">
```

Comment: I don't think he needs to surf to the post data link..

Answer (score 0):

pls see the demo code here https://codesandbox.io/s/route-params-vue-router-4-examples-forked-q6d7t8?file=/src/App.vue

I think the issue is the value of  `post_data.link` starts with a `/`